# No hardware acceleration with hd4850 card

Tags: 11.10, graphics, radeon, hardware-acceleration

I have a selfbuilt computer with asus a7n8x-e motherboard that has given me headache ever since lucid. Bought a new graphic card, hd4850, agp8x.1gb memory. Fglrx no luck, games ok but otherwise laggy feeling and freezing now and then, specially when I'm doing something important... Open drivers much much better. Drivers from xorg-edgers gave me acceleration and hope. Until the ocelot... glxinfo looks good, but it is not. Can't use anything with 3d. Happy with 2dunity so no problem, but there are other apps that I really want to use, say Stellarium for example.

My guess is two or three things that causes problem: incomplete r600gallium driver? Pregallium worked ok. Agp? Everywhere says r600g is ready enough. Not for me, so I'm looking at my old agpslot... And finally kms... ?

Any suggestions, please!

Answer (score 1):

Your card is supported by the latest Catalyst release 12.1 as well as the open source driver. You may want to install the ATI driver and check it's performance.

There is a good installation guide on the [ATI Wiki page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide) for 11.10 that should give you all the information you need to install the drivers and fix any issues.